# generating a static markup with reactjs

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs

I'm looking for a simple solution for when my project is on a shared host and it does not have nodejs installed and i want to use `react js` (seo friendly).

I came up with a solution myself: Generating a static markup with `nodeJs` on development and using laravel `blade` syntax so i can get data from database perhaps.

```
var require = require('react');
var fs = require('fs');
var Welcome = require('./react/welcome.js');

var path = __filename.split('\/');
// rendering the component to string
// passing `props` with blade syntax
var reactComponent = React.renderComponentToString(Welcome( {name:"{{$name}}"} ));

// get the name of `jsx` file
filename = path[path.length - 1].split('.')[0];

// rendering the component on the client side
reactComponent += '<script>' +
    "React.renderComponent(Welcome({name:'{{$name}}'}),     document.getElementById('welcome'));"+
    '</script>';

fs.writeFile('app/views/react/'+filename+'.blade.php', 
    reactComponent, 
    function (err) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('All down!');
    }
);
```

From here i just create a `master` template and use `@include('react.welcome')` to get the mock.

I can guess that this is a bad idea but why?

If it's not that stupid does this give me any performance boost?

Answer (score 0):

This seems vulnerable to XSS (Cross-site scripting). In general, generating JS or any code by concatenating strings is bad idea, because you lose the safety and error-handling that an interpreter / compiler / linter / etc. provides pre-runtime.

For example, here you will not be able to debug your component in any meaningful way, besides your "err" callback.

Furthermore, this pattern will quickly become unwieldy as you add more and more code.